# Teamcity, passing the user who triggered the build to powershell script

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I would like to pass my powershell build step script the user who is currently logged in teamcity and triggered the build to run. I have tried to approach it in a different way where a user checks in a file which would contain the users user name but my PM insists that I use teamcity to pass the user. I have tried

```
%teamcity.auth.userid%  or %System.teamcity.auth.userid%  or %env.username% or 
%teamcity.agent.jvm.user.name%
```

and none of them are giving me the proper user name. Could someone help please ?

Comment: I am going to see if upgrading teamcity to 8.1 gives me `teamcity.build.triggeredBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username`

Comment: Thanks, for this to work you would need groovy plugin for teamcity or you need to be on teamcity 8.1 EPA version